# How to assign namespace prefix & namespace attribute from one xml to another using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to convert INPUT XML, such a way that all elements in INPUT XML will be enriched with namespace, namespace prefix, as specified in the TEMPLATE XML. Can this be achieved through XSLT? Please help.

**Input XML:**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getCustomerInfoInput>
    <Address>
        <City>Ams</City>
        <Street>Cnet st</Street>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <City>Lon</City>
        <Street>high st</Street>
    </Address>
    <CustomerId>12345</CustomerId>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>first</FirstName>
        <LastName>last</LastName>
    </Name>
</getCustomerInfoInput>
```

**Template XML:**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:getCustomerInfoInput xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/schemas/Service/MediumLevelSchema/getCusotmerInfoSchema.xsd">
    <ns0:Name>
        <ns1:FirstName xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/schemas/Service/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd"/>
        <ns1:LastName xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/schemas/Service/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd"/>
    </ns0:Name>
    <ns0:Address>
        <ns0:Street/>
        <ns0:City/>
    </ns0:Address>
    <ns0:CustomerId/>
</ns0:getCustomerInfoInput>
```

**Expected Result:**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<ns0:getCustomerInfoInput xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/schemas/Service/MediumLevelSchema/getCusotmerInfoSchema.xsd">
    <ns0:Name>
        <ns1:FirstName xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/schemas/Service/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd">first</ns1:FirstName>
        <ns1:LastName xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/schemas/Service/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd">last</ns1:LastName>
    </ns0:Name>
    <ns0:Address>
        <ns0:Street>Cnet st</ns0:Street>
        <ns0:City>Ams</ns0:City>
    </ns0:Address>
    <ns0:Address>
        <ns0:Street>high st</ns0:Street>
        <ns0:City>Lon</ns0:City>
    </ns0:Address>
    <ns0:CustomerId>12345</ns0:CustomerId>
</ns0:getCustomerInfoInput>
```

**I tried implementing this with Java earlier, but it didn'
t produce the expected result.**

I initially tried achieving this using Java (complete code given below). Logic that I was trying in this : iterate through all the nodes of both INPUT and TEMPLATE XMLs. If the element names matches in both, then pick up the namespace, namespace prefix for the corresponding element and set it to INPUT XML node. **This almost worked for me, except that, it didn't allow me  to use setPrefix()**. So the resulting XML document looks similar to what I want, but without namespace prefix in all elements. Since this was getting too complicated in Java (tried various other options as well), I have started looking for options like XSLT. I have never used XSLT so far. Any help with XSLT will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.DocumentTraversal;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeFilter;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class EnrichXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, Exception {

        String dataXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><getCustomerInfoInput><Address><City>Ams</City><Street>high st</Street></Address><Address><City>Lon</City><Street>central st</Street></Address><CustomerId>12345</CustomerId><Name><FirstName>first</FirstName><LastName>last</LastName></Name></getCustomerInfoInput>";
        System.out.println("Data XML: " + dataXML);
        Document dataXMLDocument = stringToDom(dataXML);

        String templateXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <ns0:getCustomerInfoInput xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.example.com/schemas/MediumLevelSchema/getCusotmerInfoSchema.xsd\">     <ns0:Name>         <ns1:FirstName xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.example.com/schemas/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd\"/>         <ns1:LastName xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.example.com/schemas/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd\"/>     </ns0:Name>     <ns0:Address>         <ns0:Street/>         <ns0:City/>     </ns0:Address>     <ns0:CustomerId/> </ns0:getCustomerInfoInput>";
        System.out.println("Template XML: " + templateXML);
        Document templateXMLDocument = stringToDom(templateXML);
        templateXMLDocument.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        DocumentTraversal docTraversalDataXML = (DocumentTraversal) dataXMLDocument;
        NodeIterator nodeItrDataXML = docTraversalDataXML.createNodeIterator(dataXMLDocument.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

        for (Element dataXMLNode = (Element)nodeItrDataXML.nextNode(); dataXMLNode != null; dataXMLNode=(Element)nodeItrDataXML.nextNode()) {

            DocumentTraversal docTraversalTemplateXML = (DocumentTraversal) templateXMLDocument;
            NodeIterator nodeItrTemplateXML = docTraversalTemplateXML.createNodeIterator(templateXMLDocument.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

            for (Node templateXMLnode = nodeItrTemplateXML.nextNode(); templateXMLnode != null; templateXMLnode=nodeItrTemplateXML.nextNode()) {

                if(dataXMLNode.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase(templateXMLnode.getLocalName()) && dataXMLNode.getPrefix() == null) {
                    dataXMLNode.setAttribute("xmlns:"+templateXMLnode.getPrefix(), templateXMLnode.getNamespaceURI());
                    //dataXMLNode.setPrefix(templateXMLnode.getPrefix());
                }

            }
        }
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(dataXMLDocument), new StreamResult(writer));
        String xmlString = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");
        System.out.println("Final XML: "+xmlString);
    }
    public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) 
            throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
    }

}
```

### This Java code produces this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<getCustomerInfoInput xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/schemas/MediumLevelSchema/getCusotmerInfoSchema.xsd">
    <Address>
        <City>Ams</City>
        <Street>high st</Street>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <City>Lon</City>
        <Street>central st</Street>
    </Address>
    <CustomerId>12345</CustomerId>
    <Name>
        <FirstName xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/schemas/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd">first</FirstName>
        <LastName xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/schemas/MediumLevelSchema/GenericInfoSchema.xsd">last</LastName>
    </Name>
</getCustomerInfoInput>
```

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved with XSLT.  If you show what you've tried so far and explain exactly where the problem is then we can help you debug it.

Comment: @IanRoberts - I have updated my post with options that I tried before posting XSLT related question.